# Web-service taking too long running from cron job

Tags: php, ubuntu, drupal, cron

I have web call made in drupal 7 which does some interaction with amazon sqs and make some entries to database. Problem is that when I run that URL directly from browser it takes 20 to 30 seconds but when I schedule this url through cron job it takes 2 minutes. I am viewing the call time graph through newrelic. I have checked my code twice but there seems nothing problematic. Cron runs every 5 minutes.

Following is the cron job set up:

```
*/5 * * * *  cd ~ && wget http://my-domain.com/admin/sqs/call-page > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Is there any hidden thing that cron is adding?

My server runs on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Elysia Cron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module made managing lots of long cron tasks much easier to manage.

It records the time each cron task takes to run and also shows the average time.

Whilst this isn't a direct answer to your question I think it should still help.